# openCL: how to convert uint4 to uchar4?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, opencl

I would like to convert `uint4` vector to a `uchar4` vector, but I'm not sure what is the right way to do so:

```
const uint4 res;
res = read_imageui(input, sampler, pos_read);

output[p]   = res           // error: assigning to '__global uchar4' from incompatible type 'const uint4'; 

output[p]   = (uchar4)res;  // error: invalid conversion between ext-vector type 'uchar4' and 'uint4'

output[p].x = (uchar)res.x; // 
output[p].y = (uchar)res.y; //
output[p].z = (uchar)res.z; // works, but is this the only/right way to go?
output[p].w = (uchar)res.w; //
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this for a simple conversion:

```
output[p] = convert_uchar4(res); //For a simple conversion
```

Or one of these for a handmade conversion:

```
output[p] = convert_uchar4<_sat><_roundingMode>(res); //For a precise conversion
```

Where, `<_sat>` is optional and defines if the values will be saturated when they are out of range. And `<_roundingMode>` also optional, can be `_rte` (nearest even), `_rtp` (towards inf), `_rtn` (towards -inf) or `_rtz` (towards zero)

For further questions please address to the [OpenCL Reference Card Page 5](http://www.khronos.org/files/opencl-quick-reference-card.pdf). Or [Conversion of types for OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/convert_T.html)